# Multiple Scrollable views android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

[image: This is the initial view when screen opened]

[image: This should be the view after scrolling down and soon after image is passed it should locked and bottom should be able to scroll separately]

- *1st Image shows initial view when screen opened*
- *2nd Image should be    the view after scrolling down and soon after
  image is passed it    should locked and bottom should be able to
  scroll separately*

We have used customised nested scrollview component that has the ability to disable scroll. We listen to the scroll position of main view using onScrollChanged.

LockableNestedScrollView component

```
    public class LockableNestedScrollView extends NestedScrollView {
    // by default is scrollable
    private boolean scrollable = true;

    public LockableNestedScrollView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LockableNestedScrollView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LockableNestedScrollView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return scrollable && super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return scrollable && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        scrollable = enabled;
    }


}
```

We use this to listen to scroll postion

```
    scroll_view_01.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override public void onScrollChanged() {
            System.out.println("scroll Y :"+scroll_view_01.getScrollY());
            if(scroll_view_01.getScrollY()>=350){ 
                scroll_view_01.scrollTo(0,350);

            scroll_view_01.setScrollingEnabled(false);
            }  
        }
    });
```

But the textview is not scrollable on bottom view.

How to make bottom content scrollable after locking the main scrollview?

Comment: why exactly is this running on an iOS simulator?

Comment: @REInVent its just the figma design

Comment: and a standard collapsible toolbar isn't suitable?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/CollapsingToolbarLayout